# Efeito Toggle() pra Baixo, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Tem como mudar a direção do efeito toggle() do JQuery? Por exemplo, fiz um botão que ao clicar, ele mostra e fecha uma div

```
    $('.botao').click(function(){
        $('.div').toggle(700);
    });
```

Só, que ele meio que tem uma animação automática. Da esquerda pra direita >>>
Eu queria que o efeito começasse de cima pra baixo, no caso, começar a mostrar a parte de cima da div e terminar de mostrar tudo quando embaixo aparecesse. Tem como fazer isso com o toggle()? Ou tem alguma coisa que faça?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que você esteja procurando por `.slideToggle()` ao invés de `.toggle()`, o comportamento padrão do `.slideToggle()` no jquery é "slideUp" ou "slideDown", ou seja, deslizar p/ cima e p/ baixo. Se quiser que a `div` vá p/ direita ou esquerda, tu pode utilizar o efeito "slide" disponível no jquery.

[Jquery Slide](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/)

Segue um exemplo do `.slideToggle()`

```js
$('#slide-down').click(function() {
  $('img').slideDown('fast');
});

$('#slide-up').click(function() {
  $('img').slideUp(200);
});

$('#toggle-sliding').click(function() {
  $('img').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='slide-down'>Slide Down</button>
<button id='slide-up'>Slide Up</button>
<button id='toggle-sliding'>Toggle Sliding</button>
<img height="200" width="200" src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ZlimLS8Z-_A/U3moCpwsWII/AAAAAAAAfkg/RGdEzSBHtSU/s1600/03.png' alt='hopper'>
```

Comment: É isso mesmo Mathias, descuido da minha parte de esquecer isso, muito obrigado!

Comment: @LucasCarvalho coloquei um exemplo bem mais completo na resposta, às ordens =) .

Answer (score 1):

Creio que o toggle, por si só, não tenha como mudar a direção de baixo pra cima e vice-versa.
Você pode usar: .slideToggle() ou slideDown()/slideUp()

(=

Comment: Que descuido meu rs, o .slideToggle() é o que preciso mesmo, muito obrigado, Aline!